# $\frac{a^3}{b^2+c}+\frac{b^3}{c^2+a}+\frac{c^3}{a^2+b} \geq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}+1}$

Tags: inequality

If $a>0$, $b>0$, $c>0$ and
$$
a^2+b^2+c^2=1
$$
prove
$$
\frac{a^3}{b^2+c}+\frac{b^3}{c^2+a}+\frac{c^3}{a^2+b} \geq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}+1}
$$

Comment: put $ in the title as well please.

Comment: i think you forgott some addtional conditions

Comment: Whenever you post any question on this site, do include your own research and efforts employed to tackle the problem. Also try to include the source of the question. I am advising you because otherwise your questions will be down-voted.

Comment: Try $a=-\frac12$, $b=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and $c=0$.

Comment: it must be $$a>0,b>0,c>0$$

Answer (score 2):

we have $$\frac{a^3}{b^2+c}+\frac{b^3}{c^2+a}+\frac{c^3}{a^2+b}\geq \frac{a^4}{ab^2+ac}+\frac{b^4}{bc^2+ab}+\frac{c^4}{a^2c+bc}\geq \frac{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2}{ab^2+bc^2+ca^2+ab+bc+ca}=\frac{1}{ab^2+bc^2+ca^2+ac+bc+ca}$$
we have to Show that
$$\sqrt{3}+1\geq \sqrt{3}(ab^2+bc^2+ca^2+ac+bc+ab)$$
we have $$1=a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$$ and
$$(a^2c+b^2a+c^2b)^2\le (a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^2c^2+b^2c^2+a^2b^2)$$ by CS
and $$3(a^2c^2+b^2c^2+c^2b^2)\le (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2$$ thus
$$(a^2c+b^2a+c^2b)^2\le (a^2+b^2+c^2)^2(a^2c^2+b^2c^2+a^2b^2)\le \frac{1}{3}$$